# Import data into tables from an SQL file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to move data from one db to another. Both source and destination database servers aren't connected so i cannot do tasks export into the destination tables, so far i have done the following.

1) TASKS/Generate Scripts, scheme only, generated the sql.

2) Went to the destination db and opened the sql file and created the database schema.

3) Went to the source database and did tasks /Generate Scripts this time data only option and generated the sql with data.

4) Went to the destination db and tried opening the sql data only script of size 1.4 gb
at this point i am getting the ERROR Exception of type out of memory.

HOW can i import data only sql file?

Comment: is the destination database empty? can you not backup the source database and restore the backup on to the new database server in it's place?

Comment: Take a look at this article and I also suggest you change your approach to backup/restore, it will save you a lot of hassle: http://sqlbak.com/blog/copy-a-database-to-another-server/

Comment: yes the destination database only has schema objects but no data, i cannot do a full back up, the reason i went for generate script data only option was so i could select few tables that i needed data for

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue and my solution was to insert a GO statement about every 100 lines in the script file. I achieved this with one line of Powershell like so:

```
gc script.sql | % {$i=0}{$i++;$_ + $(if($i % 100 -eq 0){"`nGO"}else{''})} Set-Content mew_script.sql
```

Comment: do i need to run the above through command line? does it modify the existing script? or i need to generate the sql data only file again with the above option. also after doing that can i go into the destination database and open the sql file

Comment: The code assumes your script file is called 'script.sql' and it will create a new file called 'new_script.sql'. You can change these names in the code to what ever you want. To run, open the Powershell console, type cd and the path to your script file followed by the enter key. Then enter/copy the code from my answer and hit enter. You should then have a new script file which is the same as your original except it will have a Go statement on every 100th line.